# 'nested fields' in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a primary field called 'Unit', and I need to specify how many objects (exhibiting great variability) were found within them. There are 116 types of these objects, which can be broken down into 6 categories. Each category dictates what attributes may be used to describe each object type. For every unit, I need to record how many types of objects are found within it, and document how many of them exhibit each attribute. I sketched out examples of the schema and how I need to apply it. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to create a table for each type, and relate them to the table containing the unit list, but then there will be so many tables (is there a limit in MS Access?). Otherwise, is it possible to create 'nested fields' in access? I just made that term up, but it seems to describe what I'm looking to do.

- Category 1 (attribs: a, b, c, d)

  - Type 1
  - Type 2
- Category 2 (attribs: x, y, z)

  - Type 3
  - Type 4

---

- Unit

  - Type 1 | a | b | c | d |
  - Type 2 | a | b | c | d |
  - Type 3 | x | y | z |
  - Type 4 | x | y | z |

---

**UPDATE:**
To clarify, I essentially need to create subtables for each field of my primary table. Each field has sub-attributes, and I need to be able to specify the distribution of objects at this finer-grained resolution.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is similar to this question on SO: [Database design - multi category products with properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1590416/1431750).

So you'll have a third table which relates each the attribute value to the Unit. And to control which attributes each Category can have, a fourth table will be required which specifies the attributes (names) for each category.

```
Unit:
    .id
    .categoryid

Category:
    .id
    .cat_name

Category_Attributes:
    .attribID
    .categoryid
    .attribute_name

Unit_Attributes:
    .unitid
    .attribID
    .attrib_value
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this reflects the problem I'm facing. To clarify, I essentially need to create subtables for each field of my primary table. Each field has sub-attributes, and I need to be able to specify the distribution of objects at this finer-grained resolution.

Comment: You don't need to create subtables. What you need is to create a relationship between what attributes each `Unit` has and what those values are. That's taken care of in `Unit_Attributes`, which takes a valid `AttribID` from `Category_Attributes` which holds the valid combos of categories and attribute names. OTOH, the [2nd answer in the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1590460/1431750) does say creating a table per category is better for the purpose of not using a **generic datatype** for each column. Otherwise, go with [soln 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1590453/1431750), as above.

Comment: I think I'll have to use the second solution, and make a new table for each of my 16 types. One think it seems you skipped over is that each type has a different datatype dependent on the category, not each unit. Each unit then has to have values filled in to denote the presence of objects of each type (most of which will be set to 0). I apologize for this extremely convoluted question and subsequent 'clarification'.